# Using updateAppWidgetOptions method of AppWidgetManager to store per-widget customization options

Tags: android, android-widget, sharedpreferences

I have three questions about *App Widget Options*:

**1)** If I want to add an option value to the options of an app widget, I should always first retrieve the widget options with `getAppWidgetOptions(int)` and then manipulate the `Bundle`, otherwise when I call `updateAppWidgetOptions(int appWidgetId, Bundle options)` I overwrite other existing options, right?

**2)** Do this options survive a reboot? I.e., if I store some informations related to a widget within a configuration activity, am I sure I'll ever find them even after a reboot? Does the system *automagically* persist them somewhere?

**3)** Is this faster than storing widget options in *shared preferences*?

Answer (score 5):

`updateAppWidgetOptions` is for launchers to call to pass information to widgets.  Widgets recieve this information in `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged`.  Widgets do not store information this way, and if they try they will be overwritten by the launcher.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, I guess so. If you want to be sure, I suppose you should just test it.
2. I don't think so. You need persistent storage like a SQLite DB or Shared Preferences to survive a reboot
3. Maybe, since it's memory based (SharedPrefs are file based).